# neo-java-web-api compiles with non-existant version

Tags: cloud-foundry, sap-cloud-sdk

I am using the SAP Cloud SDK in the dependency management section

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>sdk-bom</artifactId>
            <version>3.75.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

and when I use the dependency

```
<dependencies>
...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sap.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo-java-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.32.5</version>
    </dependency>
...
</dependencies>
```

managed by the first one, the version that tries to compile is 4.32.0, but this version doesn't exist. I need to force it to the near 4.32.5

This issue occurred from 3.74.0 version of the SAP Cloud SDK

Comment: Thank you for the finding, I can see the problem. We're looking into this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm from the [SAP Cloud SDK](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/) team and I greatly appreciate the hint. Usually we assume developers deploying to *Neo* would also rely on the internal *SAP Artifactory* Maven repository. Ihis is why the problem didn't occur earlier, I guess.

In the future we will make sure for the *Neo* dependencies from the *BOM* to rely on versions that exist both on *Maven Central* and *SAP Artifactory*. Starting from *SAP Cloud SDK* `3.76.0`.

---

It seems like your project requires the compiler to work with the dependency `com.sap.cloud:neo-java-web-api`. For some other reason the dependency is in `compile` or `provided` scope in your application.

In the future with the next major release of *SAP Cloud SDK* the *BOM* no longer defines this dependency. Maybe this will make things easier for you.

Comment: Hi, yes I have the Neo dependency in "provided" scope. Thank you for your answer